# How to make classes not run without being called?

Tags: python, windows, class, printing, message

How to prevent the execution of a class without placing it behind the main function, i need the class for execution of program. I want to use the class only after it is declared.

Code sample:

```
class Hello:
    print('this message should not have been displayed')

def main():
    print('hello world')

main()
```

Output:

```
this message should not have been displayed
hello world
```

Comment: What is the reason and use case? If you put no print, then nothing is printed..

Comment: `class` declarations are executable in Python, so no, you cannot — it's not considered "calling them" anyway. Regardless, why are you calling the `print()` function in the class body like that (instead of in a class method)?

Comment: You should `return` values that you want to deal with in your own way. `print` will just print a value. You can also nest print statements inside of methods (such as the `__init__` method of the class) so that the printing only occurs when you create an instance of a class.

Comment: `this message should not have been displayed` - you could put this inside a `method`, maybe `__init__` method.

Comment: Don't use print in your class body.Use it inside a class method

Comment: You actually *want* python to execute things. Otherwise decorators wouldn't work.

Comment: python has a default constructor (which is the class's scope) and I wanted that defalt constructor to do something only when called, just it

Comment: Besides that it is not a `default constructor` (this is not C++), just use the *so-called* constructor: `__init__(self ...)` which has already been mentioned.

Comment: You could define your class `Hello` in different module (other python file) and import that after executing `main()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can read in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions), *"a class definition is an executable statement"* so if you write `print("string")` directly, you'll see the string in your output.

If you want to use a class to print a string, you have to create a method in the new Class, like this:

```
class Hello:
    def helloPrint():
        print('this message should not have been displayed')

def main():
    print('hello world')

main()
```

Now your output will be:

> hello world

You can print the *Hello* class message by writing the following lines at the end of the previous code:

```
h = Hello()
h.helloPrint()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so while `"a class definition is an executable statement"`, not all `class` statements need to be directly inside a module. There is also this pattern:

```py
def create():
    class foo:
        a = 1
        print('Inside foo')
    return foo

print('running')

C = create()
```

Output:

```
running
Inside foo
```

This delays the `execution` of `foo` to a particular time of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write it like this... you must place it inside a method to constructor
like this one

```
class Hello():
    def __init__(self):
        print('this message should not have been displayed')


def main():
    print('hello world')


main()
hello = Hello()
```